# Can't convert .docx with inline images to .html with Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have .docx file with such fields:

{INCLUDEPICTURE \d "ooxWord://media/image1.jpg" * MERGEFORMATINET}

{INCLUDEPICTURE \d "ooxWord://media/image2.jpg" * MERGEFORMATINET}

I want to transform .docx file to .html. When I do it with MS Word new .html file is generated. Also folder {filename}_files is created. This folder contains images on which .html has references in IMG-tags.

I use Interop.Word. The problem is when I call SaveAs in code, only first image has right src with path to folder. Second image has "ooxWord://media/image2.jpg" in src. So I can see only first image when I open .html in browser. Code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wrdApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wrdApp.Visible = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(sourcePath);
wrdDoc.SaveAs2(targetPath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
wrdDoc.Close();
wrdApp.Quit();
```

I can use only Interop. Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Maybe I should pass special parameters?

Comment: Did you try any code ?

Comment: Code was added.

Comment: I recommend you first experiment in Word as an end-user, trying various SaveAs and Web setting options until Word exports to HTML in the format that best fits your requirement. Then record that in a macro and compare that output to what you're using. Word has never been a very reliable HTML out-put source - it tends to use its proprietary round-trip format, not "standard" HTML...

Comment: I will try it!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest using another library for that task. Spire.Doc is free, faster, easier and more reliable then Interop.

See example literally solving your problem below.

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Word-to-HTML-Convert-Word-to-HTML-with-C-VB.NET.html

Comment: Thank you, but I can use only Interop.

Comment: It fixed the problem, but it doesn't suit because generated .html is used like a body for Outlook MailItem.

Comment: So you used Spire? What exactly is the issue?